# Add text to the client header when using nginx reverse proxy without modifying the proxy pass

Tags: nginx, jenkins, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have Jenkins hosted at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
The jenkins path is the default /

I have a nginx server setup with reverse proxy rules.

```
location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        }
```

I need my browser to have /jenkins prefixed to all requests made. Like the below example.

Example: `http://nginxIP/jenkins/ -> http://nginxIP/jenkins/login?from=%2F`